# Apache/DNS - Pointing Domain Name to Folder in my Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I have a folder with an app that I'm serving. In my httpd.conf, I set up a virtualhost to point to that folder. During development I set it up to point to a subdomain on a domain that I own `test.development.com`. Now that I am trying to go live, I set up the virtual host to look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html_site
  ServerAlias production.com
  ServerAlias www.production.com
</VirtualHost>
```

With my registrar, I set an A record to point to my IP. DNS looks properly propagated. However, when I go to www.production.com or production.com, it doesn't reach my app. If I add `ServerAlias test.development.com` to the VirtualHost, then when I browse to www.production.com or production.com, I get redirected to test.development.com and the app works. I wan't to reach the app, but have the url be the production url. How can I do this?

**EDIT** - Adding extra info from comments below

I ran `apachectl -S` and this was the output

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:445        development.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:75)
*:80                 is a NameVirtualHost
        default server default (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1116)
        port 80 namevhost default (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1116)
        port 80 namevhost sub.development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1132)
        port 80 namevhost sub2.development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1138)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1144)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1165)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1196)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1239)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1245)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1252)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1259)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1267)
        port 80 namevhost development.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1274)
```

Comment: 1) What do you get instead of the app - what kind of error or incorrect content? 2) What's the output of `apachectl -S`?

Comment: 1) Error says: `You have arrived at a domain that is out of service` in the browser 2) No output @ShaneMadden

Comment: That's.. fishy.  Did you run `apachectl -S` as root?  Are all your virtual hosts in the `httpd.conf` or are any included in?

Comment: @ShaneMadden All hosts are in the httpd.conf ... tried `apachectl -S` again. It output something. I added it to the original question.

Comment: Is the "domain that is out of service" message from the default vhost at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1116`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden It's not. I'm not sure where that message is coming from. Default vhost contains only `DocumentRoot`, `ServerName`, and `ServerAlias`

Comment: That content's not coming from Apache itself, it won't be in the virtual host config.  It's actually content; what's in the document root for the default host?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Ah, that has an .html file with those contents. So, I guess I don't understand why I can't get to `production.com` when I have that entry in the vhosts

Comment: So all you're doing is adding that one `ServerAlias` to the vhost you have above, then reloading the config, and you get redirected to `test.` and the app works?

Comment: @ShaneMadden yes

Comment: When error message from the default vhost comes up (without the `test.` alias), are you certain that's not post-redirection to `test.`?  Confirm in the browser's address bar?

Comment: @ShaneMadden It is post redirection (if I'm understanding your question). I guess I'm not really sure why it's redirecting to `test.` in the first place. I've completely removed that from the vhost. If I'm typing in `production.com` where does it even get the instruction to redirect to `test.development.com`?

Comment: There's almost certainly something within the application itself that's been set to think the "canonical" name of the application is `test.`, so it's redirecting to where it thinks the app should be accessed.

Comment: Wow. Yeah that was it. I can't believe that eluded me. I thought it had something to do with me not knowing enough about how vhost works. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad we were able to track it down!

Comment: @ShaneMadden I appreciate it. I know it's not a conventional answer to this question. But if you want the check mark, feel free to add an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main things to check in a situation like this are -

1. Verify that the correct virtual host is serving the request, and
2. Track down the relevant configuration bits.

In this case, the wrong vhost appeared to be serving the request contrary to the configuration, but this was actually due to an unintended redirect to a subdomain; and the requests worked when the subdomain was mapped to the correct vhost as well.

When this kind of unintended redirect appears, it can be in several places -- Apache config, less-obvious Apache config (`.htaccess` files), or in the application/content that is being served, either in redirect meta tags or in application code generating a 30x response.